# Info from the URL

Tags: android

I want to create an Application, the description of it as follows

- Perform search
- Display the results.

Basically, I want to create an application for an existing web-site which does this, but my need is to create for a Mobile.

Based on the website link, it refers to some ASP pages. for e.g. http://test.com/query.asp. The website allows the user to enter various input for search.

I want to create and then send the same request to the server and get the result. How can I know what all parameters/headers it is taking and what format is the response (XML or JSON).

Below is my sample code for the Android Device

```
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        List nameValuePairs = new ArrayList(3);
        //this is where you add your data to the post method
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sel", "1"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txt", "2466"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("selr", "2011"));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        content = response.getEntity().getContent();
        return content;
```

// Update
Ok, now I am able to get the desired output from the web query.
I printed the result for my Http Post request and I saw some HTML tags in it. In short, it prints the source of the HTML page that has to be displayed.

Is there a way to display the HTML view in my Android Application? Or a way to fetch only the relavant data from the response and ignore the HTML tags etc..?

First line of the response looks like

```
06-17 16:35:21.756: DEBUG/(30307): <script language="javascript" type=text/css>
```

//

Regards,
Nirav

Comment: So, what is the your question?

Comment: How do I determine, what all parameters I need to send. I tried wireshark and capture, there is a difference between the request sent from web and my Android Emulator.

Comment: Also, I have done a little bit of WSDL programming for an Android device where in, for a WEB service, I was able to send and receive the request. OFfcourse that was done using KSOAP2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to speak with the owner/developer of the web site / service that you want to access. Only they can reliably tell you what their APIs are if you are unable to determine them yourself from WireShark captures.